# Corrupted Flash Drive files

Tags: linux, files, arch-linux, filesystems, steam

[image: Storage Device]

**Hello**,

Today in the morning I tried to continue 3D Modelling on my Steam Deck but to my surprise all my Files didn't show up. I managed to mount it but my important folders changed into weird files. Those files show space allocated to them but are inaccessible. Flash Drive was previously formatted in Windows as fat32. Since I'm fairly new to Linux I don't have any clue what is going on. Any Ideas if it is possible to get my work back ?

***Many thanks for help!***

EDIT:

fsck initially didn't work since it is for native linux system files.

I managed to recover my files by using this instead since its fat32:

> sudo dosfsck -w -r -l -a -v -t /dev/sdc1

All files changed name to .REC and weren't sorted but they seem to be working just fine. Thank god it's not lost :)

Thanks for help anyways. Issue solved !
[image]

Comment: You made backups, right? :) If not, make a safe copy of what's on the drive (using `dd`) and then use `fsck` to see if that helps (but it might wipe out everything, so definitely backup first)

Comment: You should edit your question again, cutting out the answer, and then create an answer, pasting (the answer) there.